# Python Webscrape via Scrapy or Excel Query Search?

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, scrapy

My question pertains to discovering the overall efficiency of performing a Python webscrape via Scrapy verses simply performing a Web Query search via Microsoft Excel for a particular task.

What I am trying to do is automatically extract data from the NFL website. For example, 
http://www.nfl.com/stats/categorystats?tabSeq=2&offensiveStatisticCategory=GAME_STATS&conference=ALL&role=TM&season=2018&seasonType=REG&d-447263-s=TOTAL_YARDS_GAME_AVG&d-447263-o=2&d-447263-n=1

For example, extracting the NFL Offense Rank each week on a weekly basis. I know that I can simply just copy and paste the information on to a Excel spreadsheet but that is not what I am trying to do. I'm trying to discover a way to automate the process so that I do not have to manually do it myself.

When it comes to Python Webscrape via Scrapy, the challenge is developing the code that will obtain all the information I am seeking. Is it worth developing the code if Microsoft Query search is a better alternative?

Ideally, my overall objective is to utilize either Python Webscrape via Scrapy or Microsoft Excel to pull data every week so that I don't have to manually do it myself. These include pulling data from multiple external sources and saving into one file. For example, NFL Offense, NFL Offense Passing, NLF Defense Rush, etc. I simply either run the program or open the Excel Spreadsheet, and there will be a new sheet (or a new excel file is created) with the update data so then I can go ahead and perform my data analysis.

Any thoughts or opinions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to scrape the website.

If you are familiar with Python I would recommend using the [beautiful soup package](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). It probably is the go-to framework for webscraping and all you have to identify the HTML tags which you want to scrape. It will also help looping through pages.

There are many tutorials like [this one](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-5946935d93fe) which can help you understand how to solve your problem.

Hope this helps!